# How to select option from modal drop-down menu in Selenium with Java on app based on Ionic Cordova

Tags: java, selenium, testing, ionic-framework, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and Java programming. What am I currently trying is to select an option from a drop-down menu in a modal screen using Selenium & Java and trying to automate some functional tests on a mobile application developed with Ionic Cordova. I run the app on WebView using Chrome browser.

I have tried to use Select method which unfortunately works only with select tags and not ion-selects. Also, I have tried to locate by id, xpath, cssSelector, extending the Select class, using Action class, and etc.

After extending the Select class, I tried several options (without extending the class, Selenium error appeared saying expected is select while found is ion-select).

```
IonSelect oSelect = new IonSelect(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle")));
select.selectByValue("other");
select.selectByIndex(1);
select.selectByVisibleText("None");

Another option was:

Actions vehicle = new Actions(driver);
vehicle.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle")));
vehicle.click();
vehicle.build().perform();
```

I also applied some waits and etc. (even tried thread for testing which I have read is not recommendable)

Any ideas what to do, so I could locate the elements?

Comment: Could you please provide the code showing what you already tried.

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: All I've got is just a regular exception "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: other"